# Discrepancy in DS160

Tags: usa, applications, f1-visas

My USA visa was approved but after interview I realized that I have mentioned wrong year on expiration of my passport and my visa status was approved and now it got changed to administrative process. Did anyone have an idea will they refuse my visa by mistake.

Comment: US Visa's always go into "Administrative processing" after the interview approval, and will normally stay in that state for anywhere between a few hours and a few days.

Comment: @Doc do you have a source for this? Mine never went into administrative process after approval (at least on the portal). I though administrative processing only came after a denial.

Comment: Doc is correct, they all go into processing state after the interview. If you were approved at your interview, then you shouldn't have much to worry about, as all your evidence was accepted.